# Varying the number of iterations in a for loop depending on results in the body of the for loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, iteration

Here is the code that I tried, to vary my iterations in a for loop

```
repscount <- value
for (i in 1:repscount) { 
  ##certain calculations on x
  if (x == 0) {repscount <- repscount + 1} else{}##add x to a list
}
```

But my repscount does not increase. Does is rewrite the value of repscount? Is there another way of doing this without using a while loop?

Comment: Most likely because `x` is not exactly `0`.

Answer (score 0):

your code does not work because `for` first checks how many runs it has to do. After you change`repscount` the `for` function never checks again for the number of iterations it should do. This simple example illustrates that:

```
n <- 5
for (i in 1:n) {
  print(i)
  n <- n + 1
}
```

So first the condition inside `for` is evaluate. R knows that it will do exactly five iterations and does so. The fact that n changes afterwards has no effect on that.

You could use a `while` loop instead:

```
repscount <- value
i <- 1
while (i <= repscount) { 
  ##certain calculations on x
  if (x == 0) {repscount <- repscount + 1} else {}##add x to a list
  i <- i + 1     
}
```

Here, after the end of each run `repscount` is compared to `i` and the iteration starts from the beginning only if `i <= repscount`.

Comment: Yes I know this works. But this slows my code drastically. Is there no other way?

Comment: There are certainly other ways, but none with `for loops` I am afraid. 
Also, if this slows the code, then the equivalent for loop would slow the code as well.
In general to increase performance, you would want to avoid loops if possible. Also if the list inside the body is large, than adding something to that list can also be very slow.